# SFTP permission denied

Tags: sftp, redhat, plesk

I used Plesk to open a new domain and under the "Web hosting setup for domain" I checked the  "Shell access to server with FTP user's credentials" - "bin/bash".

I can log in to the account using SFTP (port 22) but when I try to upload files I get "Permission Denied". How is that possible if I enabled it through Plesk?

Joel

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked permissions on the folder you're uploading to?

Comment: Yes,
If I turn off the "Shell access to server with FTP user's credentials" and use port 21, I can upload files...